# how to plot many x variable agaist one y variable using ggplot function in

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an excel file with multiple columns with titles as `x, x1, x2, x3, x4` etc. I am using `ggplot` function in R to plot x against x1. The code is

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x1, y = x)) + 
  geom_point(colour = "red") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", fill = NA)
```

How to modify the present code so as to plot `x` against x1, `x` against `x2`, `x` against `x3`, `x` against `x4` in the same `ggplot` function code

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55632137/6478701) doesn't use ggplot, but solves a similar problem. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Just FYI you were missing an + between the two geoms. I added it back in but wanted to bring it to your attention in case it has anything to do with your issue. Also, it's very hard to help with this without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We can't see your data or your current output.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way your `data.frame` is formated to do this easily with `ggplot2` syntax. 
Instead of having 5 columns, with `x`, `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, you may want to have a `data.frame` with 3 columns : `x`, `y` and `type` with `type` being a categorical variable indicating from which column your `y` is from (`x1`, `x2`, `x3` or `x4`).

That would be something like this :

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(data$x, 4), 
                 y = c(data$x1, data$x2, data$x3, data$x4), 
                 type = rep(c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"), each = nrow(data))
```

Then, with this `data.frame`, you can set the `aes` in order to plot `x` according to `y` for each category of your variable `type` thanks to the `color` argument.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = type)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm, fill = "NA")
```

You should check http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization for detailed explanations and customizations.

Comment: Depending on the number of columns you have, it may be easier to generalize Chaarti's answer using `colnames(d)[-1]` to get the `x1 x2 x3 ... xn` names.

Comment: There are almost certainly better ways to reformat this data than by hardcoding a new data frame, such as with `melt`, `gather`, `stack`. But it would be easier to give a good answer if the OP had included a sample of data